# Method with same name called from Interface not from Trait?

Tags: php, laravel, interface, traits

I have created same method `printData()` in the `MyInterface.php` and `MyTrait.php` and i am calling the method `printData()` from my controller which implements the `MyInterface.php` and use `MyTrait.php`. But the method is always calling from `MyInterface.php`. Please explain it why this occurs?

**MyInterface.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Interfaces;

interface MyInterface
{
    public function printData();
}
```

**MyTrait.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Traits;

trait MyTrait
{
    public function printData()
    {
        dd("From Trait");
    }
}
```

**HomeController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Interfaces\MyInterface;
use App\Traits\MyTrait;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller implements MyInterface
{
    use MyTrait;

    public function index()
    {
        $this->printData();
    }

    public function printData() {
        // TODO: Implement printData() method.
        dd("From Interface");
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way this code would work normally. Chances are you need to add `use App\Traits\MyTrait` to see the result

Comment: @apokryfos yeah i missed that, i will update my question

Comment: Methods in a class always take precedence over a method imported from a trait. [See the section on precedence in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.precedence).

Comment: Do you actually need both implementations in your class? The quickest fix for this is probably to just remove the `printData` method from your class, since they it will always use the version from the trait. It will still be considered to implement the interface, if that's a concern in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using it like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller implements MyInterface
{
    use MyTrait{
        printData as MyTraitPrintData;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->MyTraitPrintData();
    }

    public function printData()
    {

        dd("From Interface");
    }
}
```

Traits are meant to provide `reusable` methods and properties. They will not override the class's own methods. By defining `printData()` inside the `HomeController` you are actually overriding the `printData()` inside `MyTrait`. That is why you have to differentiate them from each other.

Learn more about all this in [Horizontal Reuse for PHP](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/horizontalreuse)

Answer (score 1):

The method is not calling from `MyInterface` but from `HomeController`.

The reason is because `HomeController` acquires the method from the trait `MyTrait` but then overrides it.

If you want that method in your trait, you don't need to declare an interface.

What interfaces do is forcing the classes which implements it to declare those methods, but you don't want to do that since you're creating the method in a Trait..